# Wrong File Modification Date/time on Windows

Tags: powershell, metadata

i had some old videos laying around and converted them into mp4. I wanted them to keep the old Modification Date/time so I wrote a simple powershell script. This worked fine: Windows shows me the changed date.

However if I check the metadata of the files online, most of them do not have the Modification Date/time I set them to but the date from when the conversion took place.

My script did something like this

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "$($file[$i]).mp4" -Name LastWriteTimeUTC -Value $($time[$i])
Set-ItemProperty -Path "$($file[$i]).mp4" -Name CreationTimeUTC -Value $($time[$i])
Set-ItemProperty -Path "$($file[$i]).mp4" -Name LastAccessTimeUTC -Value $($time[$i])
```

I'm just confused as why Windows shows me the desired modification date yet other services show me the real modification date and why this does not happen for all files.

Comment: Which other services are you referring to, that show the real modification date? I'm guessing what it is showing is the video metadata Encoded Date, not just the file's creation date.